# Terminology: edge weights

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

In a weighted graph, how do you call those edges with a high weight? *Strong edges? Heavy edges? Thick edges?* And what about those with a low weight? I have been wondering about that quite some time now ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's one single widely-adopted terminology about this.
Each book/author is free to call them differently.
Also, I guess there should be some threshold for considering an edge thick/thin.
So this is all kind of subjective, depends on the particular problem at hand.
All of your suggestions make sense to me.